# OpenCV: Fit ellipse with most points on contour (instead of least squares)

Tags: python, c++, opencv, computer-vision, opencv3.0

I have a binarized image, which I've already used open/close morphology operations on (this is as clean as I can get it, trust me on this) that looks like so:
[image]

As you can see, there is an obvious ellipse with some distortion on the top. **NOTE: I do not have prior info as to the size of the circle, and this has to run very quickly (HoughCircles is too slow, I've found).** I'm trying to figure out how to fit an ellipse to it, such that it maximizes the number of points on the fitted ellipse that correspond to edges on the shape. That is, I want a result like this:
[image]

However, I can't seem to find a way in OpenCV to do this. Using the common tools of `fitEllipse` (blue line) and `minAreaRect` (green line), I get these results:
[image]

Which obviously do not represent the actual ellipse I'm trying to detect. Any thoughts as to how I could accomplish this? Happy to see examples in Python or C++.

Comment: Can you post your script that you used so far?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given the shown example image, I was very skeptical of the following statement:

> which I've already used open/close morphology operations on (this is as clean as I can get it, trust me on this)

And, after reading your comment,

> For precision, I need it to be fit within about 2 pixels accuracy

I was pretty sure, there might be good approximation using morphological operations.

Please have a look at the following code:

```py
import cv2

# Load image (as BGR for later drawing the circle)
image = cv2.imread('images/hvFJF.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

# Convert to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Get rid of possible JPG artifacts (when do people learn to use PNG?...)
_, gray = cv2.threshold(gray, 128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

# Downsize image (by factor 4) to speed up morphological operations
gray = cv2.resize(gray, dsize=(0, 0), fx=0.25, fy=0.25)

# Morphological Closing: Get rid of the hole
gray = cv2.morphologyEx(gray, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (5, 5)))

# Morphological opening: Get rid of the stuff at the top of the circle
gray = cv2.morphologyEx(gray, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (121, 121)))

# Resize image to original size
gray = cv2.resize(gray, dsize=(image.shape[1], image.shape[0]))

# Find contours (only most external)
cnts, _ = cv2.findContours(gray, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

# Draw found contour(s) in input image
image = cv2.drawContours(image, cnts, -1, (0, 0, 255), 2)

cv2.imwrite('images/intermediate.png', gray)
cv2.imwrite('images/result.png', image)
```

The intermediate image looks like this:

[image: Intermediate]

And, the final result looks like this:

[image: Result]

Since your image is quite large, I think, no harm is done by downsizing it. The following morphological operations are (heavily) sped up, which might be of interest for your setting.

According to your statement:

> **NOTE: I do not have prior info as to the size of the circle[...]**

You can mostly find an appropriate approximation for the above kernel sizes from your inputs. Since there is only one example image given, we can't know the variability on that issue.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Hough-Circle is perfect for this. If you know the diameter you can get a better solution. If you only know a range this might fits best:

EDIT: The reason this works better than the fitted ellipse is: If you are looking for a circle you should use a circle as model. The [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_Hough_Transform) explains this beautiful idea.

By the way, you could have done this with opening and closing as well. (Given you now exactly how big your circle is)

```
import skimage
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from skimage import data, color
from skimage.feature import canny
from skimage.draw import circle_perimeter
from skimage.util import img_as_ubyte
from skimage.transform import hough_circle, hough_circle_peaks


image = skimage.io.imread("hvFJF.jpg")

# Load picture and detect edges

edges = canny(image, sigma=3, low_threshold=10, high_threshold=50)


# Detect two radii
hough_radii = np.arange(250, 300, 10)
hough_res = hough_circle(edges, hough_radii)

# Select the most prominent 5 circles
accums, cx, cy, radii = hough_circle_peaks(hough_res, hough_radii,
                                           total_num_peaks=3)

# Draw them
fig, ax = plt.subplots(ncols=1, nrows=1, figsize=(10, 4))
image = color.gray2rgb(image)
for center_y, center_x, radius in zip(cy, cx, radii):
    circy, circx = circle_perimeter(center_y, center_x, radius)
    image[circy, circx] = (220, 20, 20)

ax.imshow(image, cmap=plt.cm.gray)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! A couple points I should have mentioned: (a) I don't know how large the circle is, unfortunately. Could be anywhere from 10% to 90% the width of the image. (b) This has to run in near-real-time on an embedded device; I had tried HoughCircles before, but it is extremely slow (this was OpenCV's HoughCircles function though, which may be different in performance than the one you suggest).

Comment: May I ask which hardware you use and how precise you need the result? For embedded systems you could use RANSAC. This might not give you the optimal result. But it is robust. It will always return the best result found and will always take the same amount of computational time.

Comment: Hardware is quad-core @ 1.4GHz, about 400 MB RAM available. For precision, I need it to be fit within about 2 pixels accuracy.

Comment: Uh well thats quite tight. I mean some algorithms can do sub pixel accuracy. Could you explain what you mean by realtime? Realtime means the task needs to be executed in a certain time or failures can appear. Your hardware might be good enough, depending on how much time you have to carry out the computation.

Comment: I shouldn't use the word "real-time", you're right. I mean, on this hardware it should complete within about 300ms. One issue with the Hough Circles, though, is that it isn't always a precise circle, there could be a difference up up to 2% between the major and minor axes (and being able to detect this difference is important).

Comment: Well have you an example which is more like an ellipse? I guess you could still find the hough circle, subtract it and get the remaining parts. This would allow you to classify between circles and ellipses if this is the goal. I don't now how long this will take to execute. Test it. There are ways to speed this up. You could pre crop the image for example. If it is way to slow I'd suggest using a morphological approach as @HansHirse explained.