# How can I find the center of a white circle contour bordering a red rectangle with cv2

Tags: python, opencv

How can I find the center of circle when there is some retangle bordering the big circle.

I cannot get any cricle from `HoughCircles`.

```
import cv2
import os
import sys
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

circles = cv2.HoughCircles(img, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 50, param1=50, param2=30, minRadius=400, maxRadius=800)
circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
print(len(circles[0]))
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OpenCV: Fit ellipse with most points on contour (instead of least squares)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55907678/opencv-fit-ellipse-with-most-points-on-contour-instead-of-least-squares)

Comment: you can try watershed segmentation to distinguish connected segments. It can give you the true segment for only the circle.

https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/segmentation/plot_watershed.html#:~:text=The%20watershed%20is%20a%20classical,a%20local%20topography%20(elevation).